# Cordova Application Monitoring evothings Estimote/iBeacon while the app is in killed state IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, estimote, beacon

I've installed https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode and https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications in my cordova application.

I am trying to monitor for beacons in the background when my app is closed and send a notification once a beacon has been detected and is in region.

Using the two plugins the app successfully works when the user has exited the app screen but the app is still on although does not work when the user has completely killed the process.

Can this be done solely using Javascript or would I have to modify the code in AppDelegate.m?

I've tried this using the following code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL notifyEntryStateOnDisplay;
@end


@implementation AppDelegate



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"BLUETOOTH");
    if(state == CLRegionStateInside)
    {
        notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are inside region %@", region.identifier];
    }
    else if(state == CLRegionStateOutside)
    {
        notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are outside region %@", region.identifier];
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}

@end
```

Although the application does not start. I've also changed settings in my xCode [General -> Capabilities] so that Background mode and push notifications is ON.

The app does what it needs to even if in the background and not killed although stops once the app is killed. I am trying to send a notification when the app is offline that a beacon is in range so that the user can turn the app on.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. You must set `self.locationManager.delegate=self`, and make your AppDelegate implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol, specifically the `didEnterRegion` method that should be called when a beacon is discovered.
2. Beacon monitoring must be configured and initialized in the AppDelegate.  You cannot rely the plugin to do this, because it won't necessarily leave beacon monitoring active when the app switches to the foreground.
3. When testing, set up a log message or breakpoint in the `didEnterRegion` method in your AppDelegate so you know if it gets called.